# if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['pass'])

Tags: php

Today is my first time to study PHP , I am writing a simple code that will allow me to show the output "You have entered valid use name and password" if I input the correct username and password, I honestly do not know where the problem is but I this error

Warning: Undefined array key "pass" in D:\Apps\programming\compiler\Xamp\htdocs\PHP-lessons\logs.php on line 10

Warning: Undefined array key "pass" in D:\Apps\programming\compiler\Xamp\htdocs\PHP-lessons\logs.php on line 11

Here is my simple code.

```
enter code here 
    <?php
    $username = $_POST['username'] == 'admin';
    $password = $_POST['pass'] == 'admin';
    if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['pass']){
        echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
    }
?>
<body>
<form action="logs.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="username"  required="required" /> <b>username</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="password" name="username"required="required"/> <b>password</b>
        </p>
    <button  type = "submit" name = "login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you debugging your code? You should look at the contents of the Global `$_POST`, this will give you a strong clue as to what the error is referring to. Have you tried changing the value of the name attribute for your password input, from "username" to "pass", to see what happens then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass the boolean username and password variables in if statement to get the desired result.

Edited the code :

```
enter code here 
    <?php
    $username = $_POST['username'] == 'admin';
    $password = $_POST['pass'] == 'admin';
    if ($username && $password){
        echo 'You have entered valid username and password';
    }
?>
<body>
<form action="logs.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="username"  required="required" /> <b>username</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="password" name="username"required="required"/> <b>password</b>
        </p>
    <button  type = "submit" name = "login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi

Thank you so much for helping me, I tried the code you have submitted and I also notice the mistake I did it was  input type="password" name="username"

so I change it to pass,and It's working, again Thank you so much for helping :)